# Overloading Java method with concrete variants of interface

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have a class that has a function that I want to behave differently depending on the action, all of these concrete classes implement the `Action` class. I know due to overload being determined at runtime, Action a would not go into any of these functions. What is the correct way to do this without using instanceof?

Thanks!

```
    // public State myDoAction(Action action){
    //    return myDoAction(action);
    // }
    public State myDoAction(Rest action){
        Witch newMe = me.doAction(action);
        return new State(newMe,opponent,potionsList);
    }

    public State myDoAction(Cast action){
        Witch newMe = me.doAction(action);
        return new State(newMe,opponent,potionsList);
    }

    public State myDoAction(Brew action){
        Witch newMe = me.doAction(action);
        List<Brew> newPotionsList = new ArrayList<>(potionsList);
        newPotionsList.remove(action);
        return new State(newMe,opponent,newPotionsList);
    }
```

Comment: You can create additional method in `Action` interface and do your work inside this method.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you have a class `Witch` with a `doAction(Action a)` method, and several `Action`s that change the `State` of a game.

I think that **organizing your code like this is an error**:

```
 public class Witch {
    public State doAction(ActionSubtype1 a) { ... }
    public State doAction(ActionSubtype2 a) { ... }
    // ... other stuff here ...
 }
```

because it would force you to change the `Witch` class every time you include a new action. Instead, **it should be up to the `Action`s to change the `State` as needed** (or to create and return new `State`s instead of actually changing them):

```
 public interface Action {
    public State changeState(State current)
 }
```

a `State` should provide access to all the information in the game, including potions, current turn, what `Witches` there are, and so on. Then, your `Witch` class no longer knows or cares about actions, because they can be handled at the Game level:

```
public class Witch {
     // ... other stuff here ...
     public List<Action> getActions(State s) {
         // returns valid actions for the current state of the game
     }
}

public class Game {
     // ... other stuff here ...
     public void play(State initialState) {
         State s = initialState;
         while ( ! s.isGameOver()) {
             Witch w = s.getCurrentPlayer();
             Action a = letPlayerChoose(w.getActions(s));
             s = a.changeState(s);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: State is actually a snapshot of the game, and witch is part of the gamestate, which means action also changes witches, my idea was that state doAction() would call Witch doAction() and all of these would be overloaded. Is there no way to make this type of overloading work? (Yes the input would be casted as Action a)

Comment: It makes no sense for the witches to do the actions, because then they need to know what each action does, violating the principle of least access. It is better to keep all that logic inside the actions, which makes for a  much cleaner design. Gamestates and states should be the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply put the method "myDoAction" in the Action interface (or abstract class), then overload it in the subclasses.

Like this:

```
public interface Action {
         State myDoAction ();
     }
     
     public class Rest implements Action {
         public State myDoAction(){
            Witch newMe = me.doAction();
            return new State(newMe,opponent,potionsList);
        }
     }
     
     public class Cast implements Action {
         public State myDoAction(){
            Witch newMe = me.doAction();
            return new State(newMe,opponent,potionsList);
        }
     }
     
     public class Brew implements Action {
         public State myDoAction(){
             Witch newMe = me.doAction();
             List<Brew> newPotionsList = new ArrayList<>(potionsList);
             newPotionsList.remove(action);
            return new State(newMe,opponent,newPotionsList);
        }
     }
```

> Obviously, then you need to pass the objects needed by the methods to
> the "myDoAction" declarration (or set them as instance members)